# Separar una de seleccion etiqueta css en un radioButton!

Tags: html, css

Hola Amigos espero y se encuentren bien, tengo un problema y no se como resolverlo, lo que pasa es que quiero quiero separa una regla de selección de etiqueta, es decir, un input este es el código:

```
input, select {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 24px 16px 0px 16px;
    display: block;
    width: 448px;
    height: 56px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
    color: #666666;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

Como bien se sabe esa regla cambia todo y lo que quiero es que:
un input de tipo radio sea independiente aqui tengo el código que ya hace la funcionalidad que necesito este es una regla que se le conoce como selección de atributos y este es el codigo:

```
/*RadioButtons*/

/*    input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px gray;
}

input[type='radio']:checked {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px  #043263;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    margin: 20% auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background:  #043263;
}

.role {
      margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.checkbox label {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.roles {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}*/
/*RadioButtons fin*/
```

Html:

Simulador Pensión

## Simulador Pensión

### Descubre a través de este simulador, cual podría ser un aproximado del monto de Pensión que recibirás de acuerdo a los datos que nos proporciones.

--Seleccione--</option>-->
                                0

```
                        </select>
                        <label class="combo">Hijos orfandad nula</label>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                    <div class="group">
                        <select name="producto" class="Caja_txt_246" id="producto" tabindex="9">
                            <!--                                <option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>-->
                            <option value="Tarjeta de credito">0</option>
                        </select>
                        <label class="combo">Hijos orfandad sencilla</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="botonera">      
                <div id="bt_div" class="derecha">
                    <div class="group">
                        <select name="producto" class="Caja_txt_246" id="producto" tabindex="9">
                            <!--                                <option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>-->
                            <option value="Tarjeta de credito">0</option>

                        </select>
                        <label class="combo">Hijos orfandad doble</label>
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                    <div class="group">
                        <select name="producto" class="Caja_txt_246" id="producto" tabindex="9">
                            <!--<option value="" selected="">--Seleccione--</option>-->
                            <option value="Tarjeta de credito">0</option>
                        </select>
                        <label class="combo">Ascendientes</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="botonera">
                <div  id="bt_div" class="derecha" >
                    <input type="radio" name="role" value="soltero" id="soltero">
                    <span class="role" for="soltero"> Soltero</span> 

                    <input type="radio" name="role" value="casado" id="casado">
                    <span class="role" for="casado">Casado</span>                    
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="botonera">
                <div id="bt_div" class="derecha exiit">
                    <a href="https://test.bbvanet.com.mx/portalblg/portalblg/public/registrousuario?cloud=true" class="exit">Cancelar</a>
                </div>
                <div id="bt_div" class="izquierda">
                    <button type="submit" id="loginButton" name="loginButton">Siguiente</button>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

Y todo este codigo son todos los estilos css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    src: url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Book.eot);
    src: url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Book?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Book.woff2) format('woff2'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Book.woff) format('woff'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Book.ttf) format('truetype'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Book.svg#svgFontName) format('svg')
}
@font-face {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Bold;
    src: url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Bold.eot);
    src: url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Bold?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Bold.woff2) format('woff2'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Bold.woff) format('woff'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Bold.ttf) format('truetype'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Bold.svg#svgFontName) format('svg')
}
@font-face {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Medium;
    src: url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Medium.eot);
    src: url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Medium?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Medium.woff2) format('woff2'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Medium.woff) format('woff'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Medium.ttf) format('truetype'), url(https://www.bancomer.com/fbin/repositorio/BentonSansBBVA-Medium.svg#svgFontName) format('svg')
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* basic stylings ------------------------------------------ */

h1 {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Medium;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #121212;
}
h2 {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #121212;
}

h3{
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #121212;

}

.txt_forz{
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    text-align: left;    
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #666666;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}
.exit{
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Medium;
    color: #237ABA;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* form starting stylings ------------------------------- */

.container {
    max-width: 928px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.containerPaso4{
    max-width: 928px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}

.group {
    position: relative;
}
input, select {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 24px 16px 0px 16px;
    display: block;
    width: 448px;
    height: 56px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
    color: #666666;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}

div span input{
    background: #237ABA;
}





select {
    padding: 8px 16px 0px 16px;
}
.combo{
    font-size: 12px;
    top: 8px;
}
textarea {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 24px 16px 0px 16px;
    display: block;
    width: 448px;
    height: 160px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
    color: #666666;
    background: #F4F4F4;
    resize:none;
}
input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.cond {
    background-image: url(icon/warning-icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 24px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
.botonera {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 928px;
    padding-top: 32px;
}

.botonera1{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 419.5px;
    padding-top: 32px;
}

.inputsChicos{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 209.75px;
    padding-top: 32px;

}



.derecha {
    width: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
}
.derecha {
    margin-top: 9px;
    vertical-align: middle
}
.izquierda {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #237ABA;
    font-size: 15px
}
#loginButton {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Bold;
    border-radius: 1px;
    width: 132px;
    height: 56px;
    background: #237ABA;
    border: 0;
    color: #fffefe;
    font-size: 14px;
    filter: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    float: right
}
#loginButton:disabled {
    background: #E9E9E9;
    cursor: not-allowed
}
.novalid {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #D44B50!important;
    background-color: #FCDFDF!important;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 3s ease-out;
    transition: background-color 3s ease-out
}
/* LABEL ======================================= */

label {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book !important;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 16px;
    top: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
/* active state */

input:focus ~ label, textarea:focus ~ label{
    top: 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666666;
}
/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */

.highlight {
    position: absolute;
    height: 80%;
    width: 100px;
    top: 25%;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

input:focus ~ .highlight, textarea:focus ~ .highlight  {
    -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
    -moz-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
    animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}
/* ANIMATIONS ================ */

@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from {
        background: #5BBEFF;
    }
    to {
        width: 0;
        background: transparent;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from {
        background: #5BBEFF;
    }
    to {
        width: 0;
        background: transparent;
    }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from {
        background: #5BBEFF;
    }
    to {
        width: 0;
        background: transparent;
    }
}
@keyframes loading {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0)
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg)
    }
}

h1 span { color: blue; }

input[type='radio']{

}

/*RadioButtons*/

/*    input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px gray;
}

input[type='radio']:checked {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px  #043263;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

input[type='radio']:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%;
    margin: 20% auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background:  #043263;
}

.role {
      margin-right: 80px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.checkbox label {
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.roles {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}*/
/*RadioButtons fin*/




@media screen and (max-width: 945px) {
    .enviar,
    .regis {
        position: relative
    }
    select {
        width: 100%
    }
    .botonera {
        width: 100%
    }

    .botonera1{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .enviar,
    .regis {
        width: 100%;
        display: block
    }
    #loginButton {
        float: none;
        width: 100%
    }
    .regis {
        top: 70px;
        text-align: center
    }
    .enviar {
        top: -25px
    }
    input, textarea{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .botonera {
        display: block; 
        padding-top: 16px;
    }
    .derecha {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
    .exiit.derecha{
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Espero y me de a entender de lo que comente, y si hay alguna duda con gusto les escribo, saludos y buen dia.

Comment: deberias usar bootstrap para diseño de la pagina

Comment: Hola Carlos, bootstrap no se muy bien :(, si hay manera en que se pueda hacer con css puro??

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil ¿por qué debería usar Bootstrap?

Comment: @JUANJOSEBUSTAMANTESOLIS por favor, no sólo incluyas el CSS sino también el HTML relacionado, para así crear un [mcve] y poder ver el problema mejor.

Comment: Perfecto! una disculpa por eso, voy a editar la pregunta, para que tenga mayor contexto.

Comment: pues justamente bootstrap es un framework para diseño, ya tiene establecido sus reglas para cada clase y tiene mucha variedad en cuanto diseño.  deberias visitar algun tutorial de youtube  y te daras cuenta cuanto tiemo te puedes ahorrar con ese framework.

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil No todas las páginas deben diseñarse con Bootstrap porque sea un framework de diseño, hay más, todos convenientes de algún modo u otro. Bootstrap puede llegar a ocupar hasta 270KB, ¿merece la pena incluirlo en un proyecto para solucionar algo que se puede hacer añadiendo 20 caracteres más?

Comment: De hecho si tengo unos cursos Carlos, pero por mucho trabajo que he tenido no los he podido ver, ya que esto es de mi trabajo, y ya volvi a editar la pregunta @AlvaroMontoro :)

Comment: no sabia que habia proyectos de 20 caracteres xd, paso de tus comentarios @JUANJOSEBUSTAMANTESOLIS siempre pasas a molestar en los comentarios , pues deberias revisar bootstrap juan cuando termines de ver css te lo recomiendo.

Comment: Lo primero es sacar el trabajo jejej y ya luego en ratos libres comenzaré con botstraap XDD

Comment: @CarlosEnriqueGilGil No estaba intentando trollear a nadie: lo que se puede corregir con 20 caracteres es el código del usuario. Sugerir que se incluya un framework completo para solucionar un problema de estilo que se puede solucionar añadiendo `:not([type=radios])` a lo ya existente me parece excesivo. Y mi pregunta era honesta, ¿por qué usar Bootstrap en particular, en lugar de Materialize, Vuetify, Bulma o Pure.CSS? ¿Tiene alguna ventaja para solucionar el problema expuesto en la pregunta?

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios ya pude resolver este problema y efectivamente es lo que dijo Alvaro solo con esta linea: :not([type=radio]) me arreglo el problema, saludos y buena vibra. :)

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que quieres es que las reglas CSS se apliquen a los `input` pero no a los de tipo `radio` entonces puedes usar la pseudo-clase de selección [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:not()) para excluirlos. Algo como esto:

```
input:not([type=radio]), select {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 24px 16px 0px 16px;
    display: block;
    width: 448px;
    height: 56px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
    color: #666666;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

Y aquí lo puedes ver funcionando con un ejemplo, el estilo se aplica a todos los `input` menos a los radio:

```css
input:not([type=radio]), select {
    font-family: BentonSansBBVA-Book;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 24px 16px 0px 16px;
    display: block;
    width: 448px;
    height: 56px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
    color: #666666;
    background: #F4F4F4;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" />
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="number" />
<input type="radio" name="opciones" value="a" />
<input type="radio" name="opciones" value="b" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Alvaro Montoro con esta simple linea me soluciono mi problema: :not([type=radio]) de verdad muchas gracias, te mando un gran saludo. estos ejemplos como los puedo encontrar??

Comment: Ya encontre ejms, te mando nuevamente un gran saludo